# User Statistics in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, statistics, analytics

I am using Codeigniter for my current project.

The peoject is looks like a social platform,so i want to display users data on user admin panel.

I have the following types of domains for users.

http://site.com/page_name/

so `page_name` is a page of a particular user,so when that user logged in to his control panel i want to show the usage statistics of `page_name` to him.

On Cpanel we can see so many LOG programs ,is there any plugin available to integrate this on codeigniter/php ?

i heared about Awstats ,can i use it on my case ? or how they saving the data on the server,if they are using a database then i can easily get the data from datbase.

or any other methods ? custom things ?

All suggestions and opinions are welcome.

Thank you.

**Update** : I want statistics for every pages on my project

they are not in subdomains its looks like site.com/page_name .
If i can use Google Analatycs API ,then how can i track these pages ??

Comment: @DamienPirsy accepted ,but is there any custom one ?libraries,plugins etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Piwik and inserting the link into a view.
Piwik is like google analystics, but on your server. Thats what i like, nobody else can get access to your stats.

Comment: I have to agree here. Piwik also has a splendid API which is great to work with. If you search on Google You'll be able to find a CI class for it even.

Answer (score 0):

Building custom analytics isn't hard (unless you want graphs, but this is fairly easy to do with jqplot - http://www.jqplot.com/).

You could just autoload a library that would populate a db table (through a model) with current_url() or uri_string(), and then pull the stats out for each user.

Comment: I am looking for a good library that which help me to get the statistics for every page ,so that i need to use some third party clients[save data on their database].